# Run app on currently running emulator (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am beginner to Android.
I have an emulator running currently.
I created an android app.
When I run that app, it starts starting a new emulator and running in that new emulator.
But, I want to run that app in the same emulator that is being run.

Comment: can you see the emulator when running `adb devices`?

Comment: @thepoosh No, I cann't see in "running devices" even it is running :(

Comment: I am running "Nexus S by Google". Do I have to change to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the run configuration you created, select the "Target" tab. Choose the radio button "Launch on all compatible devices/AVDs". Switch the combo box below that radio button to "Active AVDs".

This will start your app on all currently running emulators.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any device under the Target section. You can try to restart the AVD manager.
to do this open your `command prompt` and enter the following command:

```
adb kill-server
```

this will stop the AVD Manager service.

then enter:

```
adb start-server
```

or

```
adb logcat
```

to start the service again. Then check if you can add your `AVD` as a `Target`.

Comment: This fixed the problem I was having, so thank you. Eclipse wont show devices running if the server is not ok. Note that ADB requires adb daemon running on the device/emulator in case it's not responding you could restart it too but its usually auto-restarting if it crashes.

Answer (score -1):

try going into the "Run Configurations" via the arrow attached to the run button in Eclipse.

then. under "Target" you can choose the "Always prompt to pick device". 
this will allow you to choose any running emulator or device.

Comment: Thanks but, I tried this too just now. It doesn't show any device under "choose runng device" even I have a deveice emulator running already.

Comment: if it doesn't show anything, your emulator cannot run the app. (maybe you're using Google APIs?)

Comment: I am running "Nexus S by Google".
Do I have to change to another one?