# Start my application on genymotion

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I have just installed genymotions, but when I try to start my app on it, as described at the end of [this paragraph](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#collapse8), eclipse starts the old emulator even if the new one(genymotion) is running. I tried to change the debug configuration but the only virtual devices that I can see in `target` are the old emulators(see the photo below).

If in `target` i follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15884680/2337094), I get the following error :

```
[2014-01-30 19:50:00 - HelloWorld] No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.
```

Moreover I followed the [FAQs](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-eclipse) that suggests how to bing the SDK. I show my configuration in the second photo.

The devices shown in the photo are all made with AVD, there aren't the one of genymotion and neither the one that is running:
[image]

Here I put the configurations of genymotion:
[image]

How can I say to eclipse to start the genymotion emulator and not the AVD one?

Comment: I always start the genymotion emulator first then try to start my application, the genymotion emulator will be detected by Eclipse

Comment: @GhostDerfel In my case it is not detected. Where can you see that is has been detected?

Comment: In the device's tab in your Eclipse.Have you started the emulator from the Genymotion Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Make sure you are using "Always prompt to pick device" since only AVDs are listed in the emulator section. Here is a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416152/cant-run-my-app-with-genymotion/21418878#21418878)

Comment: Borh your advices proved correct, If you want answer that question this are the right solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot I think you should unselect all the AVDs displayed on the list. The option you chose launches the best selected AVD by default, and optionally a device.

Also, the Genymotion instances are considered as real devices by ADB and ADT. So, as GhostDerfel mentioned, you need to run one of them before running your app on Genymotion instance.

To know all the detected devices by ADB you can look at the "Devices" section of DDMS. If a Genymotion device is detected, it should show a name like this : `genymotion-galaxy_s3....`

You can also run this command `adb devices`. The result should show something like this:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.56.102:5555     device
```

Each Genymotion machine is listed by its local IP address here.

If you can't find your Genymotion instance(s), check that you have the lastest version of Genymotion. A ADB detection bug has been fixed on [the release 2.0.2](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/changelog/#202)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i solved it by closing Genymotion and starting it from Genymotion Virtual Device Manager in Eclipse

Comment: this can easily go in comment

Answer (score 1):

i also had this problem and all tried all the above solutions and still was not working.but finally i read in the genymotion manual that u can simply drag and drop ur apk to the device and it will load and run.so i tried that and not only it worked it also seemed to solve the path problem also so that when ever i run the project it will automatically detect my device created by genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve by connecting a real device one time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the genymotion plugin. In android studio File>Settings>Plugins>Browse Repositories > install genymotion plugin. once installed a genymotion button should appear in android studio.I hope that  helpfull for you.